# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'reward_n' referenced before assignment" In OpenAI Python Scripts

Tags: python, typeerror

I am completely stuck on this error after following a tutorial online explaining the concepts of writing an OpenAI scripts in python. The complete error is:

> TypeError: local variable 'reward_n' referenced before assignment

This is my current code:

```
import gym
import random

#reinforcement learning step
def determine_turn(turn, observation_n, j, total_sum, prev_total_sum, reward_n):
    #for every 15 iterations, sum the total observations, and take the average
    #if lower than 0, change the direction
    #if we go 15+ iterations and get a reward each step, we're doing something right
    #thats when we turn
    if(j >= 15):
        if(total_sum/ j ) == 0:
            turn = True
        else:
            turn = False

        #reset vars
        total_sum = 0
        j = 0
        prev_total_sum = total_sum
        total_sum = 0

    else:
        turn = False
    if(observation_n != None):
        #increment counter and reward sum
        j+=1
        total_sum += reward_n
    return(turn, j, total_sum, prev_total_sum)

def main():

    #init environment
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    observation_n = env.reset()

    #init variables
    # num of game iterations
    n = 0
    j = 0
    #sum of observations
    total_sum = 0
    prev_total_sum = 0
    turn = False

    #define our turns or keyboard actions
    left = 0
    right = 1
    forward = env.action_space.sample()

    #main logic
    while True:
        #increment a counter for number of iterations
        n+=1

        #if at least one iteration is made, check if turn is needed
        if(n > 1):
            #if at least one iteration, check if a turn
            if(observation_n[0] != None):
                #store the reward in the previous score
                prev_score = reward_n[0]

                #should we turn?
                if(turn):
                    #pick a random event
                    #where to turn? 
                    event = random.choice([left,right])
                    #perform an action
                    action_n = [event for ob in observation_n]
                    #set turn to false
                    turn = False

        elif(~turn):
            #if no turn is needed, go straight
            action_n = [forward for ob in observation_n]


        #if there is an obseravtion, game has started, check if turn needed
        if(observation_n[0] != None):
            turn, j, total_sum, prev_total_sum = determine_turn(turn, observation_n[0], j, total_sum, prev_total_sum, reward_n[0])

        #save new variables for each iteration
        observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)

        env.render()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The thing that I do not get about this error is that all the variables are in main() or in determine turn which gets variables from the main(). So far this is my knowledge of this error and would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't expect reward before taking action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if at least one iteration is made, check if turn is needed
    if(n > 1):
        #if at least one iteration, check if a turn
        if(observation_n[0] != None):
            #store the reward in the previous score
            prev_score = reward_n[0]
```

In this part of your code you are trying to access to `reward_n[0]`, but this variable has not be initialized yet, So, you need to initialize it before its first call the same way as you did with this:

```
observation_n = env.reset()
```